# Gravity forms to civi extension for payments or Form processor and payments

Tags: contribution-page, forms

Is anyone working on this/ has done this? Or any other elegant solution? (non Drupal)

Would much appreciate people's input - sorry if this is not the appropriate forum

Comment: PS we have $ (but not many!)

Comment: maybe you could give a fuller picture of what you need the form (be it Gravity or other) actually needs to deliver in terms of functionality

Comment: Pretty much the same as the old caldera plugin. Record name address email phone & update or create new civi contact (based on civi unsupervised dedupe. ) Gravity does payment processing:  stripe to process one off and recurring. Also has  PayPal offered as alternative for one off (selected by user) Contribution details to go to civi = Total amount, financial account, payment method. We have existing gravity form which does all logic & notifications etc, We need the civi bit.

Comment: what is it that a standard civi contribution page won't do that you need. They can do "Record name address email phone & update or create new civi contact" and accept payment (sorry if i am not helping)

Comment: Thanks Pete I don't know how to achieve  utm tracking & choose between paypal and credit card in civi - only one payment processor per form I think

Comment: You can enable more than one Payment Processor on a Contribution Page in civicrm

Comment: I don't know about UTM but https://github.com/VishalAgarwal/org.civicrm.webtracking suggests it provides this requirement

Answer (score 0):

The Gravity Forms integration paid plugin created by a former Civi partner is no longer supported.

Also see: [CiviCRM + Forms: Which is best? Gravity Forms/Ninja Forms/Contact Form 7 or Civi's own Profiles?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40879/civicrm-forms-which-is-best-gravity-forms-ninja-forms-contact-form-7-or-civi)

Comment: Thanks Andy -  aware of that - didn't do payments anyway. Basically just wondering if any developments in the last 14 months since that post

Comment: Quite sure it's none